# How do you truncate values in a CSV file with python without using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, csv

How do I truncate all numbers to the 3rd decimal place in a CSV file without using pandas?

This is the CSV format.

```
Name, Type, 462.12848482,828.54892927,52.738299195920

Name, Type,85.929818284,734.89382884,938.388291
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use pandas,

```
with open('metaanalysis_data.csv', 'rb') as f_input, 
open('metaanalysis_datas.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, quotechar="'")
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))

    for row in csv_input:
        for i, elem in enumerate(row):
            try:
                row[i] = '{:.3f}'.format(float(elem))
            except ValueError: pass
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```